# Why hard links not allowed to directories in UNIX/Linux

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, hyperlink

I read in text books that UNIX/Linux doesn't allows hard links to directories but soft links do? Is it because when we have cycles and if we create a hardlinks, it will point to some garbage values?

If cycles were the sole reason behind not allowing hardlinks, then why softlinks are allowed to directories?

Comment: @bmargulies Then why is it possible with softlinks

Comment: Because the kernel doesn't follow them in the fundamental traversal of the directory hierarchy. It can walk the tree, because it doesn't traverse soft links when walking the tree.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416308/file-systems-with-support-to-directory-hard-linking

Comment: @bmargulies Could you please tell why kernel does traversal on hardlinks and not in softlinks. I mean the reason behind it. Or can I get a simple example depicting that (traversal)

Comment: I don't understand I see both hard and soft links in linux often.

Comment: You can use bind mount to simulate hard linking directories

    sudo mount --bind /some/existing_real_contents /else/dummy_but_existing_directory
    sudo umount /else/dummy_but_existing_directory

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hardlinks are not permitted because they would lead to cycles. Once you allow cycles to form, you must perform a mark-and-sweep garbage collection to detect when isolated cycles of directories (no longer reachable from the root) can be finally deleted - this is extremely expensive on disk.

Soft links do not cause this problem because they do not raise the reference count of the targeted directory; thus you can still get away with reference counting (with a maximum of one reference :).

The other issue is that programs which traverse the file system (eg, `find`) need to avoid cycles. They *could* do this by remembering every inode number they've seen, but this is expensive - if they can distinguish between links which could lead to cycles (ie, softlinks) and links which will not lead to cycles (normal directory entries), and skip the softlinks, they don't need to track inode numbers anymore.

Comment: I got the first and third paragraph right. But couldn't understand the second one. COuld you please give a more clear explanation

Comment: @user567879, in other words, if you have a soft link to a directory, it doesn't prevent the directory from being deleted and removed from disk

Comment: +1. A more detailed explanation of the 3rd paragraph: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22394

Comment: I disagree about the necessity for mark-and-sweep garbage collection. Even if cycles are allowed, you can never get into a situation where you have a cycle of objects which are not pointed to by anything except each other. This is because directories always have to be deleted depth first.

Comment: In an act of necromancy: Directories may need to be deleted depth-first, but this is something that is done in userland, not in the FS.  (I think) the FS simply refuses to delete if the directory has children -- and where foo/bar mutually contains foo/baz, both have children -- each other.

Comment: Paragraph 3 is confusing because find is not an appropriate example for your point   In fact, keeping track of inodes is precisely what find does do, because POSIX requires loop avoidance (and a diagnostic).   Take a look at the code.